# Best HTTP Method for Get or Create

Tags: api, http, rest, http-method

I'm writing an HTTP based API, and I have a situation where the user specifies a resource, and if that resource doesn't yet exist the server creates it. It's basically built on top of Django's `get_or_create` method.

What would be the most idiomatic/correct HTTP method to use in this situation?

I'm suspecting that `POST` would be proper. However, I'm not entirety sure. Though it seems that `GET` would be incorrect seeing as it's not supposed to have any side-effects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `GET` for this. Repeated calls to this end point will return the same resource, so it's still Idempotent.

Comment: That seems like a pretty reasonable justification for `GET`, thanks.

Comment: Mozilla says NO :- "GET: The HTTP GET method requests a representation of the specified resource. Requests using GET should only be used to request data"
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET

Answer (score 13):

A `GET` request expresses the user's intent to not have any side effects. Naturally, there will always be side effects on the server like log entries for example, but the important distinction here is whether the user had asked for a side effect or not.

Another reason to stay away from `GET` surfaces if you respond with the recommended `201 Created` response for a request where the resource is being created on the server. The next request would result in a different response with status `200 OK` and thus it cannot be cached as is usually the case with `GET` requests.

Instead, I would suggest to use `PUT`, which is [defined as](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.6)

> The PUT method requests that the enclosed entity be stored under the
> supplied Request-URI. If the Request-URI refers to an already
> existing resource, the enclosed entity SHOULD be considered as a
> modified version of the one residing on the origin server. If the
> Request-URI does not point to an existing resource, and that URI is
> capable of being defined as a new resource by the requesting user
> agent, the origin server can create the resource with that URI.
>
> If a
> new resource is created, the origin server MUST inform the user agent
> via the 201 (Created) response. If an existing resource is modified,
> either the 200 (OK) or 204 (No Content) response codes SHOULD be sent
> to indicate successful completion of the request. If the resource
> could not be created or modified with the Request-URI, an appropriate
> error response SHOULD be given that reflects the nature of the
> problem.

In the above form, it should be considered a "create or update" action.

To implement pure "get or create" you could respond with `409 Conflict` in case an update would result in a different state.

However, especially if you are looking for idempotence, you might find that "create or update" semantics could actually be a better fit than "get or create". This depends heavily on the use case though.

Comment: Yes. This. I can't believe this isn't the accepted answer :/

Answer (score 1):

I would not use `GET` for creating resources because you never know if some robot (like a search engine robot) is following listed `GET` calls which would then create a lot of useless resources.